# What binning or group technique is this of Python or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, regression

I'm fairly new to Pandas and I understand to handle data it is often a good practice to in them, create dummy variables or even create new columns in the DataFrame.
However I came across these lines of code and cannot understand what it does. It was intended to group  data of1 categorical column into 3 columns by age.

```py
ratings_df.loc[(ratings_df['age'] <= 40), 'age_group'] = '40 years and younger'
ratings_df.loc[(ratings_df['age'] > 40) & (ratings_df['age'] < 57), 'age_group'] = 'between 40 and 57 years'
ratings_df.loc[(ratings_df['age'] >= 57), 'age_group'] = '57 years and older'
```

It doesn't create a new column, or a new Dataframe by given name. But it's later used to train data in a regression model with another independent variable 'beauty'

```
lm = ols('beauty ~ age_group', data = ratings_df).fit()
```

What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to view the lines of code as such:

```py
condition = (ratings_df['age'] <= 40)
column_name = 'age_group'
new_value = '40 years and younger'

ratings_df.loc[condition, column_name] = new_value
```

So in short, the column named `age_group` is having a new value set `"40 years and younger"` for every row for which `ratings_df['age'] <= 40` is true.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank You @kd88 . How can I access all the rows that satisfy said condition

Comment: No worries - you can simply do `ratings_df.loc[condition]` to retrieve those rows

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @kd88's nice answer, you noted that "no new column is made", if you take the code in stages you can see that `loc` sets a value when the condition is met and sets `NaN` if it is false, so you're building up the new column in 3 stages:

```
In [98]: ratings_df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [20, 40, 41, 50, 57]})
In [99]: ratings_df.loc[(ratings_df['age'] <= 40), 'age_group'] = '40 years and younger'
In [100]: ratings_df
Out[100]: 
   age             age_group
0   20  40 years and younger
1   40  40 years and younger
2   41                   NaN
3   50                   NaN
4   57                   NaN
```

Depending on what you want to do with the data you can use `query` to get a *view* into a subset of the rows (but don't try to modify these or you'll get an error):

```
In [101]: ratings_df.query('age <= 40')
Out[101]: 
   age             age_group
0   20  40 years and younger
1   40  40 years and younger
```